# Stripe integration - Payment Intent with checkout redirection

Tags: javascript, java, html, stripe-payments

I am working on to upgrade the checkout process to make it SCA complaint. As per their doc I need to use the PaymentIntents for it.
And I did follow the steps mentioned in their document: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/web

Now I was able to configure it properly but in this document it mentioned to have stripe-card-element. But I need to use the checkout redirection process instead of this card element.
Need to use this :

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migration
[image]

If somebody know please share some info. 
FYI, I already reached their customer support but they are taking way too long to respond and I am in hurry.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using updated Stripe Checkout (that does the redirect for you), you do not need to create PaymentIntents manually. Checkout uses PaymentIntents under the hood and will automatically do that for you.

It looks like what you want is the client-server Checkout integration: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/one-time#client-server

i.e. create a Checkout Session server-side, then use Stripe.js and `redirectToCheckout` to redirect to the Checkout page using the session ID.

There is also a client-only integration that you could leverage: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/one-time#client-only